# $f:[0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R},\ \int_0^1f(t)t^pdt=0\ \forall p\ge 0\Rightarrow f=0?$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, continuity

Let $f:[0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $\int_0^1f(t)t^pdt=0$ for all integers $p\ge 0.$ Does that imply $f=0$ ?
I know that's true if $f$ were continuous on $[0,1]$ instead of $[0,1)$ but I don't know the answer in this case.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is $f$ bounded? Otherwise the integrals might be undefined.

Comment: I'm assuming that $f$ is $L^1$ on $[0,1]$. Then you can use uniform approximation to show that $\int_0^1{f(t)e^{2in\pi t}\,dt}=0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. It follows that $f$ is orthogonal to any bounded function on $L^2$, but $f$ is a $L^1$-limit of bounded functions, so $f=0$.

Comment: @Mindlack thanks, I actually know that the result holds if $f\in L^1([0,1]) as well$ (i should have said that). My problem is what if $f$ isn't integrable.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Not necessarily, we just suppose the integrals are convergent and are equal to 0.

Comment: I think you can integrate by parts. If $F$ is the (continuous on $[0,1]$) antiderivative of $f$, then $F$ satisfies the same property and $F(0)=F(1)=0$, so $F=0$ by the continuous case and thus $f=0$.